# NGX-CHIPS not rendering Firebase returned list

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase-realtime-database, ngx-chips

I am using [NGX-Chips](https://github.com/Gbuomprisco/ngx-chips/) in Angular. I am saving the typed in chips into Firebase and retrieving them.

Problem is, when it tries to render the saved chips, it can't and throws an error.

Before posting this question, I tried to read through and follow this issue on GitHub and added the `displayBy` and `identifyBy` tag with no avail.

**THE ERROR**

```
Error: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed
```

**HTML Code**

```
<tag-input 
     (onAdd)="onCategoryAdded($event, product.external_id)" 
    [displayBy]="'display'"
    [identifyBy]="'$key'" 
    [(ngModel)]="product.categories"
    [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
    theme="minimal" 
    placeholder="Categories"
>
 <tag-input-dropdown [autocompleteItems]="categories"></tag-input-dropdown></tag-input>
</tag-input>
```

In my controller, I set an observable item, listen for value changes and assign those to mentioned observable.

```
public products: Observable<any[]>;

ngOnInit() {
   this.products = this.afd.list('/products').valueChanges();
}

onCategoryAdded(event, product) {
  this.afd.database.ref('/products').orderByChild('external_id').equalTo(product).once('value', (snapshot) => {
    snapshot.forEach((product) => {
      this.afd.database.ref('/products').child(product.key).child('categories').push({
        'display' : event.display,
        'value' : event.value
      });
    });
  });
}
```

`product.categories` prints out like below when I add `{{product.categories | json}}` to my html.

```
{ "-LfN8VhSrWBye-8ukSAq": { "display": "Featured", "value": "Featured" } }
```

Should I alter how I save the categories in Firebase so it returns a different value or should I transform the returned value somehow within the controller?

Answer (score 0):

Just as described in the error NGX-CHIPS is waiting for an array and you are passing an object

`Error: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed`

You are passing this to NGX-CHIPS

```
{ "-LfN8VhSrWBye-8ukSAq": { "display": "Featured", "value": "Featured" } }
```

you need to convert this json/object to an array you can do that using the map operator

```js
// don't forget to import the operator

import { map } from 'rxjs/operators'


ngOnInit() {
   this.products = this.afd.list('/products').valueChanges().pipe(
map(list => {

      const productsArray = Object.keys(list).map(key => {
         const item = list[id]; // [{display: 'Featured', value: 'Featured'}]
         item.key = key;  // [{key: "-LfN8VhSrWBye-8ukSAq", display: 'Featured', value: 'Featured'}]
         return item;
      });

   }));
}
```

Comment: Where is `id` defined in `list[id]`. Also this manipulates the entire products array. The categories are a child of the product.

Comment: Any ideas on how we could filter just that object for each product?

Comment: Firebase does not return an array it returns an object, so if you want to iterate through them you will have to convert that object to an array. Like what I did in my answer.

But you still need an identifier to be able to reference the document when you update it, that is why I took each object key and added into every object inside that array